# I can't display my database table in the dgv (at the first 5 lines)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a problem of my dgv (C#),in fact I can't display the table "fichier" in the first 5 lignes(which is the table length).I get the result from the other side of the dgv(when i place the cursor,like a have a double of the dgv => the first five lines are empty but the other side when I move the cursor the data is displayed).I don't know where the problem is.
this is my code (the table should be appear when the form loads):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter dr;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string pat, req;

        public Form2()
{
            try{
    pat = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrateur\\Bureau\\Copie de WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\AppData\\Main.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    req = "SELECT * FROM fichier";
    con = new SqlConnection(pat); 
    con.Open(); 
    dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, con); 
    dr.Fill(ds, "fichier");
            }
            catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show("database not find", e.Message); } 

            InitializeComponent();
            panel2.Hide();
            affich();

        }

        private void affich()
        {

          // MessageBox.Show(""+sTable.Rows.Count); //the result is 5
          // MessageBox.Show(""+sTable.Rows[0][0].ToString()); //the result is 11
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["fichier"];
        }
```

this is the result in the dgv when the form loads (before) and after the cursor's deplacement:

[image]

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add one of these lines right after you call "affich()" in your Form2() constructor...

Either

`dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);`

or

`dataGridView1.Update();`

Comment: thanks Ruslan but I get the same result all the time :(

Comment: @Lina Even after adding those lines? Just to confirm - the data comes up when you click on the data grid, right?

Comment: Have you tried calling dataGridView1.Refresh() instead?

Comment: yes,thanks Ruslan my problem was solved by using the MainDataSet option :D thanks a lot for your help